# Has rx Function Action1 been deprecated?

Tags: android, rx-binding

I have a use case within my Android application where I wish to allow the user to enter a "certain amount" of text to search on before starting a search. As the user types additional text I would like to initiate further searches using the complete text entered.

Having researched a number of options I found Jake Whartons `RxBinding` library and felt this would be a good solution

using code such as this:-

```
RxTextView.textChanges(editTextVariableName)
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String value) {
                    // do some work with the updated text
                }
            });
```

However I cannot import `Action1`, is the above code no longer valid?
which dependency am I missing?

My gradle file resembles this

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton.rxbinding2/rxbinding
implementation group: 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2', name: 'rxbinding', version: '2.1.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton.rxbinding2/rxbinding-appcompat-v7
implementation group: 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2', name: 'rxbinding-appcompat-v7', version: '2.1.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton.rxbinding2/rxbinding-support-v4
implementation group: 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2', name: 'rxbinding-support-v4', version: '2.1.1'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxandroid
implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxandroid', version: '2.0.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava
implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.1.10'
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need `Action1`? If you're able to set the Android language level to 8, you can just use a lambda there; otherwise you can just use `Consumer<String>` instead of `Action1`.

Comment: There is no `Action1` in RxJava2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the documentation of [RxJava 2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0) "Action1 has been renamed to Consumer" so it still exists and has not been deprecated, just renamed